# Question Regarding the Time Complexity of Algo Finding Common Elements in Unknown Number of Arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

I am having difficulty understanding the time complexity for my code below regarding the return of common elements in an unknown number of arrays. I was told that my time complexity was O(n^2). However, my understanding is that since I am running a computation on each element (where n equals the total number of elements in each nested loop) only once the time complexity would be O(n).

I have tried researching time complexities pertaining to looping through 2D arrays, but have found multiple answers regarding this topic.

My question is: Am I right in assuming that the complexity for this algorithm can be interpreted by how n is defined. For example, if I were to define n as the number of nested arrays the time complexity would be O(n * c), where c is the number of columns? As opposed to defining n by the total number of elements in each nested array, where the complexity would be O(n) as explained above? Thank you for considering my question.
`

```
const commonElements = (...args) => {
  const hash = {};
  const commonEls = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < args[i].length; j++) {
      if (i !== args.length - 1) {
        hash[args[i][j]] = (hash[args[i][j]] || 0) + 1;
      } else if (hash[args[i][j]] > i - 1) {
        commonEls.push(args[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
  return commonEls.length ? commonEls : "Nothing in Common!";
};
```

`

Comment: "the complexity for this algorithm can be interpreted by how n is defined" - the complexity of any algorithm is a function of its input size, so yes.

Comment: "The complexity" is a misnomer. You define a function that describes some quality of your code that you'll call "time" -- for example, the number of comparisons -- based on some parameter of your input -- for example, the number of elements in your array, and then compute the complexity class of this function. Except in narrow fields (like when you're studying formal complexities like NP/P), exactly what "time" is, and exactly what "n" is (or even if it's multiple parameters) is up to you although often there are obvious or common choices.

Comment: In this case, I personally would say that it's O(n) comparisons (being pedantic about time being comparisons, and assuming it's obvious what "n" is), but it's also fine to say its time complexity is O(n) or even O(sum(len(arg) for arg in args)). Complexity is a tool for communication and analysis, and not some absolute truth except when you're actually doing formal complexity theory.

Comment: @PaulHankin thank you so much for your explanation of the wider meaning of complexity and the importance of how we interpret and define functions that describe an attribute of a piece of code. This conversation has shown me the importance of understanding the role of interpretation within this topic and clearly defining specific parameters when discussing time complexity.

Comment: @Nelfeal Thank you for taking the time to respond to my inquiry. I appreciate your insight. I am learning so much through these conversations.